# Pod file with hidden sources (Framework only)

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Hello stack overflow users. Im trying to create pod with no source code inside.
I read a lot of tutorials and trying to follow them but getting strange error.
I have this podfile.spec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.name         = "sdkTEST"
s.version      = "0.0.1"
s.summary      = "A nice logger tool in Swift."
s.description  = "DESC"

s.homepage     = "https://github.com/test_user"
s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "license" }
s.author       = { "Sergey" => "sergey@gmail.com" }
s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'sdkTEST.framework'
s.source            = { :http => 'https://github.com/LLTemp/test_sic_zip/raw/main/sdkTEST.zip' }
s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"

end
```

But when Im calling

```
pod lib lint
```

Im getting this error

```
- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing

```
pod lib lint
```

pod actually not download the source from **s.source** url (imo this is bug) and use you local version of framework. You can put the *.framework file in you library path and the error will go away.

One more thing for those who interesting in publishing the pod without sources.
To use actual pod the Podfile should look like this

```
target 'OpenSSLTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'
  pod 'test_sic', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LLTemp/test_sic/1.0.12/test_sic.podspec'  
end
```

Pay attention to use **:podspec** and not **:git** or **:http**